# SARMA model as infinite AR

Tags: r, time-series, arima, seasonality

Can anyone reference an algorithm or paper which can help me convert a general SARMA model to an infinite AR polynomial in backshift operator B? I would like to do this in R somehow.

$$ \frac{\theta(B)\Theta(B^s)}{\phi(B)\Phi(B^s)} = 1 - \pi_1B - \pi_2B^2 - ... $$

Comment: This may be of limited value if the sample size is less than the order of the "infinite polynomial" .

Comment: Yeah I was hoping to find an algorithm where I could stop calculating $\pi$ weights at any point I choose.

Comment: Polynomial arithmetic is what AUTOBOX implements to do this  ... also make sure to include differencing operators

Comment: In principle, a SARMA process is just an ARMA process with coefficient restrictions - so you can find the AR representation through matching coefficients, as for example explained here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171698/how-to-calculate-impulse-responses-for-a-given-autoregressive-process/171709#171709