# How do you find the variance for an AR(p) process?

Tags: time-series, variance, arima, autoregressive

Does it exist a general formula for finding the variance for an AR(p) process?

I know there is one for AR(1).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

As explained in, e.g., [How to calculate impulse responses for a given autoregressive process?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171698/how-to-calculate-impulse-responses-for-a-given-autoregressive-process/171709#171709) you can write the AR(p) process as an $MA(\infty)$ via comparing coefficients to obtain
$$
Y_t=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\psi_j\epsilon_{t-j}
$$
Then,
$$
Var(Y_t)=\sigma^2\sum_{j=0}^\infty\psi_j^2
$$
as the $\epsilon_{t-j}$ are uncorrelated.

Answer (score 0):

The [Yule–Walker equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model#Yule%E2%80%93Walker_equations) give you a formula for the variance. But there are many other possibilities for estimating it.

Comment: Thank you, do you know if there exists a general formula for variance for a MA(q) process?

Comment: MA(q) is a special case of my formula above for $MA(\infty)$