# Autocovariance function of autoregressive process, generalized to any order

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, autoregressive

I have calculated the autocovariance function in the AR(1) case, which was quite easy, but I need the autocovariance function for higher order AR(p), assuming it is still stationary. I have been searching online, but I have had a surprisingly hard time finding any direct function. Does a function even exist in a closed form? Where can I go to read more about this? Specifically, I need the following:
$$ \gamma(a)=\text{Cov}(y_i, y_{i-a}),\: \text{where }y_i = \phi_1 y_{i-1}+\phi_2y_{i-2}+\dots+\phi_py_{i-p}+\varepsilon_i$$

Comment: You can write the process as an $MA(\infty)$ as in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/577595/how-do-you-find-the-variance-for-an-arp-process/577604#577604 for which you could find the coefficients as in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171698/how-to-calculate-impulse-responses-for-a-given-autoregressive-process/171709#171709