# How $\psi_{j}$ weights of the AR(p) process satisfy the difference equation?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, autoregressive, differencing

The parameters $\phi_{1}, \phi_{2}, \ldots, \phi_{p}$ of an AR(*p*) process
$$ z_{t}  = \phi_{1} z_{t-1} + \cdots + \phi_{p} z_{t-p}  + a_{t}  $$

or

$$ (1-\phi_{1}B-\cdots-B^{p}) z_{t} = \phi(B) z_{t} = a_{t} $$
whre $B$ is the back shift operator. This general AR(*p*) process can be written as

$$ z_{t} = \phi^{-1}(B) a_{t} = \psi(B) a_{t} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \psi_{j} a_{t-j} $$

Since $\psi(B) = \phi^{-1}(B) $ so that $\psi(B)\phi(B) = 1 $, The weights $\psi_{j}$ for the AR(*p*) process satisfy the difference equation

$$\psi_{j} = \phi_1 \psi_{j-1} + \phi_2 \psi_{j-2} + \cdots + \phi_p \psi_{j-p} \quad j >0  \qquad (1)$$

with $\psi_{0} = 1$ and $\psi_{j} = 0$ for $j < 0$.

**Question**: How can we derive and find the difference equation (1) for $\psi_{j}$ weights of AR(*p*) and why condition of $j > 0$ is applied in equation (1)?

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171698/how-to-calculate-impulse-responses-for-a-given-autoregressive-process/171709#171709

Comment: @ChristophHanck mentioned link also give some help.