How is mean-reversion behavior captured within ARIMA models? What coefficients determine speed of mean-reversion?
Suppose we have an AR(1) model:
$X_{t} =\phi X_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t}$.
If $|\phi|<1$, then $X_{t}$ process follows a mean-reverting behavior. Now, instead of simple AR(1) model, let's consider the following ARMA(p,q) model:
$X_{t} =\phi_1 X_{t-1} + ... + \phi_p X_{t-p} + \theta_1 \epsilon_{t-1}+ ... \theta_q \epsilon_{t-q} + \epsilon_{t}$.
Is there any direct way to describe mean reversion behavior of $X_{t}$ process through the ARMA coefficients? I assume that mean-reversion behavior should be described with a combination of above mentioned coefficients, like in the stationarity condition. If so, does stationarity condition for ARMA indirectly describe the mean-reversion behavior of the process?
EDIT In addition to the above question, what coefficient or combination of coefficients determine speed of mean-reversion? (Should be the sum of all AR(p) coefficients?)

Related: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/79123/is-it-possible-to-discretize-ou-with-a-more-general-arp-arma-p-q-models

Related, but not the same.

Similar enough to be worth linking, I think.

I would, but do not know how to do.

I would suggest to find the $MA(\infty)$ representation (e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171698/how-to-calculate-impulse-responses-for-a-given-autoregressive-process/171709#171709) and see if the impulse responses die out at long horizons.

@Sane, I provided a link in my first comment. This is what I meant by linking, so that has already been done. (I have not suggested closing one as a duplicate of the other or anything like that.)

@ChristophHanck But what coefficients describe mean-reverting pattern? MA's?

The coefficients of the $MA(\infty)$ representation of an ARMA process are a function of both the AR and the MA coefficients. Whether these die out is however determined by the AR coefficients, as these are ultimately "responsible" for whether the process is mean reverting (the MA part, as its name may suggest, is transitory).

Let $\hat x_t=E(x_t\mid x_1,\dots,x_p)$ denote the expectation of $x_t$ conditional $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_p$.   I leave it as an exercise to show that $\hat x_t$, for $t>p+q$, satisfies the homogeneous difference equation
$$
\phi(B)\hat x_t=0.
$$
Using standard methods for solving such equations, the solution has the form
$$
\hat x_t = E(x_t\mid x_1,\dots,x_p) = c_1 r_1^t + c_2 r_2^t + \dots c_p r_p^t
$$
where $r_i$ is the reciprocal of the $i$th root of of the autoregressive polynomial $\phi(z)$.  These $r_i$ are all smaller than one in absolute value for a stationary ARMA model.  Asymptotically, for large $t$, the rate of mean reversion is thus determined by the $r_i$ with the largest absolute value.

Very interesting!

@RichardHardy Well, I don't know, this is nothing new but just how the forecast behaves forward in time which I believe is included in most introductory treatments of ARMA models?

I do not remember having seen your last equation before. Perhaps I have, perhaps I have not. The benefit of a failing memory is the enjoyment one gets from rediscovering forgotten things :)

Jared: As a follow up Richard's question, do you know of a book or paper that covers the part about the speed of reversion being a function of the largest root of the characteristic equation and all that sort of thing. thanks.

@mlofton https://civil.colorado.edu/~balajir/CVEN6833/lectures/wwts-book.pdf section 5.6

@Jarle Tufto: Thanks so much. Shockingly, I have that book somewhere but don't look at it enough.

@JarleTufto You define speed of mean-reversion in terms of the largest $r_{i}$. Can we define in terms of the AR/ARMA coefficients?

The largest $r_i$ is a function of the ARMA parameters.  Given the AR-coefficients $\phi_1,\phi_2,\dots,\phi_p$ contained in a vector phi in R, the largest $r_i$ can be computed by max(1/Mod(polyroot(c(1,-phi)))).

Doesn't this mean that mean-reversion speed is just captured by the largest coefficient from the series $\hat{\phi_1}, \hat{\phi_2}, ..., \hat{\phi_{p}}$?

@Sane No, I would suggest that you study https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients

Assuming the AR(p)
$$ X_t = \mu + \phi_1 X_{t-1} + \phi_2 X_{t-2} + \ldots + \phi_{p} X _{t-p} + \epsilon_t.$$
is specified correctly, (i.e: invertible and $y_t$ is stationary ), then the  long term mean of $y_t$ is $\mu$ and it converges to this mean in the sense that any impulse response ( i.e. a shock ) dies off eventually as $n \rightarrow \infty$. So, if there are no new shocks at time $t$ and forward, then for some large $n$, the prediction of the AR(p), $\hat{y}_{t+n}$, will eventually become $\mu$. This what I mean by convergence.
Note that, when you add the MA terms back in and make it an ARMA, that doesn't change the argument above because the error terms associated with the MA terms are not permanent errors. The MA error terms go into "y_t" and eventually also die out due to the invertibility of the AR component. By invertibility of the AR component, I just mean that the roots of the characteristic equation of the difference equation associated with the AR piece are all less than one.
In summary,  what I am saying is that, by definition, any ( non-trending and non-seasonal ) ARMA model that is specified correctly is mean reverting to whatever it's mean $\mu$ is. The time to reversion of course depends on the AR coefficients and the assumed impulse etc.
ADDENDUM: ML: 04-27-2024
THE SECOND PART OF YOUR QUESTION WAS HOW TO FIGURE OUT WHAT THE RATE OF MEAN REVERSION WAS GIVEN THE AR(p).
For the AR(1), $X_{t} = \mu + \phi X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$,
the half-life is calculated by using the fact that it is defined as the number of timesteps it takes for the response to become half of what it was originally. So, Suppose $X_{0} = 0$ and $\epsilon_{0} = 1$.
Then, by definition, $\rightarrow \phi^{\textrm{half-life}} = \frac{1}{2}$.
Taking logs gives $\textrm{half-life} = \frac{\log\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\log(\phi)}$. So, for the AR(1), as $\phi$ goes down, the half-life  increases ( which means reversion speed decreases ) because the smaller value of $\phi$ means that more steps are needed for the response to get back to $\mu$, given the impulse $\epsilon_{0} = 1$.
But, in the AR(p), in a sense, each of the $p$ coefficients has its own half-life so they interact in a complex way. One method would be to do what Jarle suggested. Obtain the the reciprocal of each of the  roots of of the autoregressive polynomial $\phi(z)$. The impulse response asymptotically is the maximum of these reciprocal roots multiplied by the associated $c_{i}$ coefficient.
I doubt very much that there is a closed form solution for the half-life of an AR(p) because it requires a complex convolution.
But, rather obtaining the dynamics by using Jarle's asymptotic approach, here's a suggestion:
I have shown you how the impulse response works in the AR(1) case. So, one could conceivably do the same thing for the AR(p) case. The only difference is that, at each time step, instead of the impulse response being $\phi$ then $\phi^2$ then $\phi^3$  and then $\phi^4$ etc, $\ldots \phi^n$, upto whatever, in the AR(p) case there are $p$ coefficients so the multiple effects need to be bookkept correctly and then added up at each time step $t$. This can get out of hand quickly
and prone to error.
So, the simplest thing to do is just plot the impulse response. How to do that is straightforward:  The AR(p) is:
$$ X_t = \mu + \phi_1 X_{t-1} + \phi_1 X_{t-2} + \ldots + X_{t-p} + \epsilon_t.$$
So, in say R or matlab, estimate your AR(p) in order to obtain the $\hat{\phi}_{i}$ estimates.  Then, take the AR(p) expression above and  set $\mu = 0$, $\epsilon_{0} = 1$, and all $X_{i}$ to zero. Then, substituting the estimates in place of the actual values of $\phi_{i}$, see what happens to $X_t$ in the equation above $\forall t=1,2,3,\ldots, \infty$. The plot is the impulse response.
So, what I have provided  is a programming method for obtaining the impulse response exactly. I doubt very much that there is a closed form solution for the half-life of an AR(p) because it requires a complex convolution that someone would have figured out by now and published !!!!
The upside is that, asymptotically, it should match with the method that Jarle suggested. So, you have a way to check it by calculating the reciprocal roots of the AR(polynomial) and taking the maximum.
Note that the calculation of the roots of the AR (polynomial) is done over and over when the AR is estimated in R so it doesn't cost much to calculate the roots in R either. The only difference is that Jarle's approach is asymptotic so doesn't give you the response for finite time steps. If there are a lot of coefficients, the impulse response for finite time steps could differ considerably.
I hope this helps as an answer to the second part of your question.

Thank you for this answer. In actuality, I have additional question above. Could you please elaborate that part too?

Hi Sane:  yes, the speed of reversion is a function of the sum of the coefficients. Let me see if I can find something helpful for you to read because the ARDL setting is very similar to the ARMA and there's a nice political science paper that describes what you're asking. I'll look for it and hopefully include it in a follow up comment.

Sane: The papers I was going to link to are not as relevant as I had hoped. Also, I take above back. The long term multiplier is a function of the sum of the coefficients. Jared  says ( and I believe him ) that  the speed of reversion is a function of the maximum root of the characteristic polynomial of the AR component. I'd have to delve into the literature to read about that but I have no intuition there.  I also have a question for Jared.

Did you find any documentation about ARMA coeffs and mean-reversion speed? So far, I did not

Hi Sane: I didn't but I think the answer is embedded in Jarle's response. I looked in Brockwell and Davis because that's usually my "go-to" text for more esoteric topics but no luck. I also googled. No luck. Note that the idea ( which has its roots in what Jarle said ) of it being the largest half life kind of makes sense to me.  So, the answer might be to calculate the half life lives for each of the coefficients and then take the maximum.  That's a guess. Do you know how to obtain the life for the simple case of the AR(1). If so, do the same thing for each coefficient and take the max.

I'm gonna check out section 5.6 in the text that Jarel pointed to above in response to my question. But eyes are closing so I will check it out over the weekend.

Sane: If you're not familar with the half life calculation in the AR(1) case, it's just $\frac{log(\frac{1}{2})}{log(\phi_{i})}$ where $\phi_{i}$ is the $i$th coefficient being used.

Some of the info that Jarle wrote is explained in slightly more detail in this document. https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/153-fall2010/lectures/7.pdf. So, as far I can see, Jarle's suggestion of taking the largest root will work but one would need the associated $c_{i}$ coefficient to actually generate the impulse response plot. Instead,  if you just took the max of the half iives, then you don't need the $c_{i}$ coefficient so plotting the impulse response is easier.  But, as I said, I'm not 100 percent certain about taking the max of the half lives.

Hi Sane: I've been thinking about this a little so I'm putting an addendum to my original answer as suggestion to the second part of your question.  But the suggestion is not a closed form expression for the halflife. The coefficient with the maximum halflife will drive ( dominate if you will ) the impulse response of the AR(p) in the long run but the actual dynamics need to be plotted.

HI! Thanks a lot for your answer and the comments. I will have a closer look at your materials and will get back to you. Thank you!!

Sane: It's a long winded answer but, to summarize, I believe the best thing to do is just plot the impulse response in R or Python.  AFAIK, Ii's not possible to get a closed form solution for the impulse response of an AR(p). You can use the asymptotic approach suggested by Jarle but just  plotting it gives you more info and it's exact rather than an approximation.

I think you make a mistake in half-life. See https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30213/how-to-find-the-formula-for-the-half-life-of-an-ar1-process-using-the-ornstei

Sane: quantuple's answer is the same as mine so I'm not clear where the mistake is ? Just in case you didn't notice:  in the numerator, quantuple uses 2 instead of 1/2 but  he put's the negative sign out front.

Oh, yeah, my mistake ... sorry.

No problem. A while back, I answered a question of yours about transition density for the AR(1) and then I modified the answer in the comments a few days later because I did make a mistake. So just a heads up that I made that change in case you didn't see it.

Yes, I have noticed. Thanks a lot!
